# Python recognizing \r as a line delimiter

Tags: python, line-endings, file-io

I'm using `import fileinput` in a Python script running on an Ubuntu box.

I'm running the script on the command line with something along the lines of `python myscript.py firstinputfile.txt secondinputfile.txt` and inside `myscript.py` I am using `for line in fileinput.input()` to iterate over the lines.  The problem I'm running into is that `firstinputfile.txt` and `secondinputfile.txt` both use Macintosh (`\r`) line endings, and `fileinput.input()` does not seem to be recognizing `\r` as a line delimiter.

*Is there any way to force `fileinput` to recognize `\r` as a line delimiter?*

I've considered preprocessing `firstinputfile.txt` and `secondinputfile.txt` to use `\n` line endings, but am hesitant for two reasons: i) I don't really want to emit additional files to manage and ii) I still want the input to `fileinput` to come from file arguments (not `stdin` after piping commands) so I can use `fileinput.filename()` and `fileinput.filelineno()`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you replace `\r` with '\r\n' in the files.. before reading

Comment: @avasal I could, but I'd rather not have the side effects.  Ideally I want to be able to take files as input in the state I receive them and output what I need without creating any intermediate state/mutating the input source.

Comment: then probably if the file is not too large, you can read all the contents as a string and split using '\r' creating a list and then iterating over it

Comment: @avasal as per the question this would complicate the script further because I would need to keep track of which list items were associated with which input files in order to display this information when I need it.  It might not add a lot of complexity, though I'd certainly prefer a solution that doesn't require it if one is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out [fileinput.input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) supports an optional `openhook` parameter:

> You can control how files are opened by providing an opening hook via
>   the openhook parameter to fileinput.input() or FileInput(). The hook
>   must be a function that takes two arguments, filename and mode, and
>   returns an accordingly opened file-like object. Two useful hooks are
>   already provided by this module.

Furthermore, the [universal newline support](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.4/whatsnew/node7.html) document suggests that a file can be open to support Windows/Unix/Macintosh newlines with the `rU` mode:

> Opening a file with the mode 'U' or 'rU' will open a file for reading
>   in universal newline mode. All three line ending conventions will be
>   translated to a "\n" in the strings returned by the various file
>   methods such as read() and readline().

So, you can write a little function to pass as the `openhook` argument that will open the file in a manner which supports universal newlines:

```
def univ_file_read(name, mode):
    # WARNING: ignores mode argument passed to this function
    return open(name, 'rU')
```

Then, instead of:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
```

Use:

```
for line in fileinput.input(openhook=univ_file_read):
```

This seems to have done the trick for me, and `\r` is being recognized as a line delimiter now.