# Python readline() fails when trying to read large (~ 13GB) csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm a Python newbie and had a quick question regarding memory usage when reading large text files.  I have a ~13GB csv  I'm trying to read line-by-line following the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and more experienced Python user's advice to not use **readlines()** in order to avoid loading the entire file into memory.

When trying to read a line from the file I get the error below and am not sure what might be causing it.  Besides this error, I also notice my PC's memory usage is excessively high.  This was a little surprising since my understanding of the **readline** function is that it only loads a single line from the file at a time into memory.

For reference, I'm using Continuum Analytic's Anaconda distribution of Python 2.7 and PyScripter as my IDE for debugging and testing.  Any help or insight is appreciated.

```
with open(R'C:\temp\datasets\a13GBfile.csv','r') as f:
        foo = f.readline(); #<-- Err: SystemError: ..\Objects\stringobject.c:3902 bad argument to internal function
```

UPDATE:

Thank you all for the quick, informative and very helpful feedback, I reviewed the referenced link which is exactly the problem I was having.  After applying the documented 'rU' option mode I was able to read lines from the file like normal.  I didn't notice this mode mentioned in the documentation link I was referencing initially and neglected to look at the details for the **open** function first.  Thanks again.

Comment: Try opening the file with the 'rU' flag. Check out this question (particullaty the update from the asker) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844523/unable-to-read-huge-20gb-file-from-cpython

Comment: This is almost certainly a dup of that question. The problem is that, as far as Python 2.x is concerned, in non-universal mode, that file (or most of it) is one giant line, with millions or `\n` characters in it, but no `\r\n` sequences.

Comment: As a side note, you usually don't even need `readline`—you can just do `for line in f:`, or, even better, use a higher-level library like [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to parse the data for you.

Comment: (Note that using `csv` magically takes care of newline problems for you, on top of making other parts of your code simpler and more robust.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix text files end each line with `\n`.

Windows text files end each line with `\r\n`.

When you open a file in text mode, `'r'`, Python assumes it has the native line endings for your platform.

So, if you open a Unix text file on Windows, Python will look for `\r\n` sequences to split the lines. But there won't be any, so it'll treat your whole file is one giant 13-billion-character line. So that `readline()` call ends up trying to read the whole thing into memory.

The fix for this is to use [universal newlines](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode, by opening the file in mode `rU`. As explained in the docs for [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> supplying 'U' opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or the Windows convention '\r\n'.

So, instead of searching for `\r\n` sequences to split the lines, it looks for `\r\n`, or `\n`, or `\r`. And there are millions of `\n`. So, the problem is solved.

---

A different way to fix this is to use binary mode, `'rb'`. In this mode, Python doesn't do any conversion at all, and assumes all lines end in `\n`, no matter what platform you're on.

On its own, this is pretty hacky—it means you'll end up with an extra `\r` on the end of every line in a Windows text file.

But it means you can pass the file on to a higher-level file reader like [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that wants binary files, so it can parse them the way it wants to. On top of magically solving this problem for you, a higher-level library will also probably make the rest of your code a lot simpler and more robust. For example, it might look something like this:

```
with open(R'C:\temp\datasets\a13GBfile.csv','rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        # do stuff
```

Now each row is automatically split on commas, except that commas that are inside quotes or escaped in the appropriate way don't count, and so on, so all you need to deal with is a `list` of column values.

Comment: Thanks again abarnert, I neglected to mention this was being done on a Windows platform with a file that was generated on an Ubuntu box which explains why Python was trying to read the entire file into memory for the exact reasons you describe.  I'll look into Python's **csv** module as well and see about leveraging that in my code, thanks and Happy New Year :)